# CSS Timer text moves when it comes at number 1

Tags: css, timer, width

Does anybody knows how to change the width of a character? I have a timer and the position is good, but when it comes at number 1, the width of the timer will be smaller. It should be the same position all the time. Is there anybody who knows the solution for this? I'm using Digital-7 as font.

CSS:

```
#time {
                        font-family: digital-7;
                        font-size: 60px;
                        position: absolute;
                        margin: auto;
                        top: 65px;
                        left: 342px;
                        color: white;
                        text-align: right;
                        display: block;
                        width: 30px;
                        text-align: right;
                        letter-spacing:5px;
                    }
```

HTML:

```
<span id="time"></span>
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: best would be jsfiddle or working code here in SO

Comment: I tried jsfiddle but it didn't worked :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is, that you are using font that is not monospaced (all letters use same "invisible box" placed behind), so the solution for you, can be to switch the font - and this requires no additional coding.

Your font is also provided as monospaced, so try it out > [digital-7](http://www.dafont.com/digital-7.font)

Comment: Yes, got it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
display: block;
```

Probably using a div is better suited for this purpose

Comment: `display: block` solves only size of the holding element (span or div) but it won't solve movement of font inside. additionally, by setting `block` it may break the layout, so `inline-block` could be a better solution for designing the holding element (for font movement, see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

The text-align property is the root cause of the issue. find a way to get rid of it.